# Is It necessary I have an apple computer to publish a "codenameone app" into apple store?

Tags: codenameone

I developed an App using CodeNameOne Framework.

To publish this app in the apple store, do I need to have an apple computer?
Using CodeNameOne Wizard, could I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time you need a mac. You can use [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) or a similar service to perform the task using the Application Loader tool. We can build our own submission tool but this requires some effort and wasn't requested by enterprise developers.

Comment: Hi Shai. Thank you for your response.